# minimum trace spacing error

Tags: pcb, kicad, clearance

A PCB made with KiCad has a configured clearance of 0.152 (6mil) but when I send it to JLC site I have this warning:
"Attention please, the minimum trace spacing is out of our capability, your order may be canceled"
And in the analysis detail it says:
"minimum trace spacing : 0.96 mil"
I made a DRC check and nothing was reported, I guess that if some track was dragged too close to another then I'd have an error, right?
Is it the manufacturers check that is not working? How can I make sure my KiCad PCB is ok?
Thanks in advance,
Pedro
[image: drc control image]
[image: design rules editor]
[image]

Comment: PCBNew -> Tools -> DRC.

Comment: @vofa please make a (full-sentence) answer out of that. It **is** the right answer!

Comment: "minimum trace spacing : 0.96 mil" suggests that you have a violation in the gerbers, even if not in the design.  Perhaps you have things on what are intended to be different layers combined on the same layer, or have a non-copper layer being interpreted as copper.  Or potentially you even have a very narrow gap in something supposed to be connected.  They aren't looking at your netlist, but rather running some kind of connectivity analysis on the exported artwork.  Examine your design in a stand-alone gerber viewer.

Comment: Similar to the comment from Chris, are you using any floating polygons, symbols, fills, or text on a copper layer? If the board house does a clearance check using only the gerber files any two floating objects might trigger a clearance error if positioned very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pcbnew, click Tools -> DRC. This open the Design Rule Checking (DRC) tool. It checks trace spacing (clearance), as well as trace widths and via sizes. Minimum clearance between traces is set up in the Design Rules tool.

If you have errors, such as two traces being routed too close together, the tool will tell you where they are. Reroute the traces as needed and re-run the DRC. Keep doing this until you have zero errors. Never send a board to be manufactured without doing DRC.

You should also use the 'Check Unconnected' tool in the DRC to make sure you haven't missed any connections.

Comment: thanks for your quick comment! I just edited my question to add that information... In fact I did it...

Comment: this is the report file:  ** Found 0 DRC errors **

** Found 0 unconnected pads **

** End of Report **

Comment: If it passes DRC and you're sure the correct gerber files were sent to the manufacturer, I would ask them where on the board they see the clearance error. It could be a misunderstanding.

Comment: also be double sure that you've defined the clearance for the right tracks, and that your gerber export settings don't mix up dimensional units

Comment: thanks for you quick help, that info reassures me :-) I'll double check the gerber export and then I'll ask the manufacturer where do they see the issue

Comment: found nothing strange, placed the order, waiting for the manufacturers reply, I'll post it here for reference

Comment: If the board shop's minimum space spec is .006 inch, and you are working to 0.152 mm, there may be a rounding error converting between inches and mm causing an apparent error - my calculator says 0.152 mm = 0.00598 inch (5.98 mil)